# Get INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements executed at specified time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

We are investigating some issues with our production database where some suspicious records inserted/updated in our database. I just wanna know how we will be able to get these TSQL statements executed at a specified time. We are SQL Server 2014 with a FULL recovery option.

Sorry for my ignorance (I am not a DBA and we don't have any).

Comment: If there is no DBA then, I assume auditing will not be enabled - Please confirm this. Is there any trigger in place for insert/update/delete on the subject table where IUD has taken place?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Will ApexSQL Log help to get the statements executed?

Comment: Yes, it is likely that a 3:rd party log reader tool can be of help here. Note that those transactions can be in the active log (ldf) or a log backup file (assuming you haven't deleted those required log backup file already). The tool in question should support reading the log from the right source, but I have a feeling that a decent log reader tool support reading from both sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no auditing enabled to capture CDC(Change Data Capture) and no trigger defined on Insert/Update/Delete statement then, I don't think its possible to get details.

If you enable them now then, you would be able to capture them in the future. There are tonnes of article on how to configure auditing over SQL server. Full recovery can only help you in restoring database upto a specified point in time however that again depends how frequently you are taking log backup.

Hope above helps.